# Fixed height input field on focus 'centers' the input

Tags: html, css

I have an input field where I add a fixed height. However, when I focus on said height, the height turns back to the original one...What I mean by that is that when I focus it, the 'area' where I write is in the center of the input field, while I want it at the bottom of the input field.

The reason why I want that is because I want a label inside the input field, so I increase the height of the input field, and stack the label behind the input field and have a transparent background on the input field. Here's the code and the demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6uLnreu5/1/):

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7vh;
  z-index: 10;
  color: black;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.test-label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 2%;
  margin: 0;
  top: 5%;
  color: #778692;
}
.form-field {
  height: 7vh;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <p class="test-label">Input</p>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

How would I go to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably add some padding to the top and include the

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

So that your padding doesn't effect the size of the box.

The issue you will have, is your text's height is not dependant on the height of the view, whereas your input field is. So you will find inconsistent results on different height screens.

Here's an example JS fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6uLnreu5/3/

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `padding-top` instead of fixed height. `input {padding-top: 20px;}`

Answer (score 0):

you should define a `font-size` on your `.test-label`, and the set `padding-top` on the `input` equal to the `font-size+x px` where `0<=x<=somevalue` as per your need of gapping between the label and text write area. Check out the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6uLnreu5/7/
Additionally, you have to set `box-sizing: border-box` on the `input` so that its height does not increase beyond `10vh`